# Unable to retrieve class variables to be used in other classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

Thank you for checking out this post

Hey guys, I know the title seems simple, but I have tried everything I could think of and the various methods I found online and nothing is working. At this point, I am assuming the problem lies within my code structure itself but I have no clue where

I am trying to create a database for storing information typed in `Entry` widgets and other variables. However, the database lies in its own class, while the `Entry` widgets and variables lie in another. I will only show two of these needed variables because once I solve one, I am fairly sure I can solve the rest

Class with the `Entry` widgets:

```
# Class for the Registration Window
class registrationWindow_2():
    # Function for initialising the Registration Window
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.title("HealthSync")
        self.master.geometry("1000x1000")
        self.master.iconbitmap("Assets/PLACEHOLDER_LOGO.ico")
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        # Label for Window Title
        self.label_RegistrationTitle = tk.Label(master, text="HEALTHSYNC REGISTRATION [Page 1]", width=200)
        self.label_RegistrationTitle.place(x=500, y=20, anchor="center")

        self.fullname(master)

    def fullname(self, master):
        # Variable for asking for name input
        self.enterName = tk.Label(master, text="~Please enter your full name~")
        self.nameRegister = tk.Entry(master, borderwidth=7) # <--------------------------------------

        self.enterName.place(x=500, y=40, anchor="center")
        self.nameRegister.place(x=500, y=70, anchor="center")

        self.nameRegister.insert(0, "-Full name here-")

        # Button for confirming inputted Name
        self.button_confirmName = tk.Button(master, text="Is this your name?", padx=100, bg="#A9A9A9",
                                            command=self.function_confirmInput)
        self.button_confirmName.place(x=500, y=100, anchor="center")

        # Button for moving to Phone Number registration
        self.button_nextInput = tk.Button(master, text=">>", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#A9A9A9", state="disabled",
                                          command=lambda: self.phoneNumber(master))
        self.button_nextInput.place(x=500, y=135, anchor="center")
```

and here's the other one (in the same class as before)

```
    def find_age(self, master):
        self.dob_date = self.birth_cal.get_date() # <------------------------------------------------
        self.dob_list = self.dob_date.split("/")

        self.ageConditon = 0

        self.currentDate = date.today()
        self.currentDateReformat = self.currentDate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        self.today_list = self.currentDateReformat.split("/")

        if self.dob_list[2] > self.today_list[2]:
            self.ageConditon = 2
        else:
            if self.dob_list[2] == self.today_list[2]:
                self.ageConditon = 1
                self.actual_age = int(self.today_list[1]) - int(self.dob_list[1])
            else:
                self.actual_age = int(self.today_list[2]) - int(self.dob_list[2]) # <----------------

        self.confirmAge = tk.Button(master, text="Is your age confirmed?", padx=90, bg="#A9A9A9",
                                    command=self.function_confirmInput)

        # Button for moving to Height registration
        self.button_nextInput = tk.Button(master, text=">>", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#A9A9A9", state="disabled",
                                          command=lambda: self.height(master))
        self.button_nextInput.place(x=500, y=655, anchor="center")

        self.displayAge(master)
        self.confirmAge.place(x=500, y=620, anchor="center")
```

As you can see, the first one has just one variable I need (which applies to most of the others) while the second one has two variables that I need (Only case)

Here is the database code I have so far, the one enveloped with hashtags is the problem area

```
class database(object):
    # Function for creating a database
    def __init__(self):
        database_check = os.path.exists("HealthSync_user_information.db")

        if database_check == False:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect("HealthSync_user_information.db")
            self.cursor_variable = self.connection.cursor()

            # Create table
            self.cursor_variable.execute("""CREATE TABLE HealthSync_user_information (
                                                        userName text,
                                                        password text,
                                                        gender integer,
                                                        fullName text,
                                                        phoneNumber integer,
                                                        dateOfBirth text,
                                                        age integer,
                                                        height float,
                                                        drugAllergy string,
                                                        foodAllergy string,
                                                        insectAllergy string,
                                                        latexAllergy string,
                                                        moldAllergy string,
                                                        petAllergy string,
                                                        pollenAllergy string,
                                                        illnessHistory text,
                                                        area text
                                                        )""")
            self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.close()
        else:
            pass
###################################################################################################
    # Function to enter data into database (WIP)
    def submit(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("HealthSync_user_information.db")
        self.cursor_variable = self.connection.cursor()

        # self.cursor_variable.execute
        self.cursor_variable.execute("INSERT INTO HealthSync_user_information VALUES (:userName, :password, :gender, "
                                     ":fullName, :phoneNumber, :dateOfBirth, :age, :height, :drugAllergy, :foodAllergy,"
                                     ":insectAllergy, :latexAllergy, :moldAllergy, :petAllergy, :pollenAllergy,"
                                     ":illnessHistory, :area)",
                                     {
                                         "userName": registrationWindow_1.username.get(), # <----Here
                                         "password": registrationWindow_1.password.get(),
                                         "gender": registrationWindow_1.gender.get(),
                                         "fullName": registrationWindow_2.fullname.get(),
                                         "phoneNumber": registrationWindow_2.phoneNumber.get(),
                                         "dateOfBirth": registrationWindow_2.find_age.dob_date,
                                         "age": registrationWindow_2.find_age,
                                         "height": registrationWindow_2.heightRegister.get(),
                                         "drugAllergy": registrationWindow_3.drugAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "foodAllergy": registrationWindow_3.foodAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "insectAllergy": registrationWindow_3.insectAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "latexAllergy": registrationWindow_3.latexAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "moldAllergy": registrationWindow_3.moldAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "petAllergy": registrationWindow_3.petAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "pollenAllergy": registrationWindow_3.pollenAllergy_Details.get(),
                                         "illnessHistory": registrationWindow_3.illness_Register.get(),
                                         "area": registrationWindow_3.area_dropdown.get(), # <--To here
                                     })
###################################################################################################
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```

Just to repeat what I am trying to accomplish, I am trying to take the data from the two examples given first given and call it in the Database class

Any questions, please feel free to ask

I am still a student, so any reworking or correcting will be very much appreciated to help me further my knowledge as a budding programmer, thank you!

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. Your question could probably be expressed with two example classes, and all this other stuff is just a distraction.

Comment: But basically, one of your classes will want to take the other as a dependency.  For example, pass in a `database` object to your other class, and then use the database as needed.

Comment: My bad on that, I assumed I cut out the fat enough with only giving two variables and the database class. Will definitely work on this in the future, thank you for the feedback

Comment: and what do you mean by "pass in a database object to your other class"?
If you mean `ClassName(database):`
wouldn't that make it so I need to `super()` the `__init__` of those classes?

Comment: What? No, not at all. You don't need inheritance (you *never* need inheritance).  When you initialize your first object, pass it in as an argument. so `Foo(bar)` where `bar = Bar()` your other object. So just add another parameter to `__init__`, in addition to `master`, say, `db` and then you have `self.db = db` and you can use `self.db` in any method

Comment: @MichaelGuidry um, actually, a body being *composed* of different body parts is a perfect example of an abstraction that doesn't require inheritance. In any case, it is a tool that you can *choose* to use, but isn't required, and indeed, is greatly overused. Consider `golang`, no inheritance. Somehow, it gets along just fine. I'm going to go with the judgement of Ken Thompson and Rob Pike that it isn't required.

Comment: Have you created an instance of your class `registrationWindow_1` before you call the `submit` method?